# Editing custom NSCell

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nscell

I'm in the process of creating a custom NSCell, which will work like the shortcut capture cells in XCode, and trying to figure out how to intercept edit requests (for instance, when a user double-clicks a cell). Is there some way to determine that an edit is being initiated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking specifically to detect a double-click in a cell? If so, `setDoubleAction:(SEL)aSelector` is what you're looking for.

Or is the question more generically about detecting when a cell will enter 'editing' state? In that case, see the table delegate method `tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:`